# Why do I get this unexpected output here? "87"

Tags: c

I can't explain to myself, why this would give 87. My IDE is codeblocks and my compiler GNU GCC Compiler.

```
unsigned long getHigherValue(unsigned long Value1, unsigned long Value2); 

int main(){
  int a, b = 20;
  b = 22;
  /*============
  It works fine if I replace the two lines above with "int a = 20; int b = 22"
  =============*/
  int c = getHigherValue(a, b);
  printf("%d", c);

  return 0;
}

unsigned long getHigherValue(unsigned long Value1, unsigned long Value2){
  unsigned long HigherValue = Value2;
  if(Value1 > Value2){
  HigherValue = Value1;
  }
  if(Value1 == Value2){
  HigherValue = 0;
  }
  return HigherValue;
}
```

Output:

> 87

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int a, b = 20;
```

This leaves `a` uninitialized, and `b` initialized to 20.  The value of `a` is **indeterminate**, therefore you could get any result from your program (i.e. it's **undefined behaviour**).

Comment: So now that the question is really too simple: Why is the undefined behaviour always the same? i.e. I get 87. Does this have to do with how it is placed in memory? My goal was to get some knowledge anyway :)

Comment: @Yannis: It's likely that you're just seeing whatever rubbish happened to be in that register or stack location at the time.

Comment: @Yannis - use a different HW platform or a different compiler, and you will see different values.  The actual value (87 byte followed by three zeroes) is most likely a local variable or a parameter passed by whatever the CRT startup code called just before calling `main`.  Get familiar with some compiler options of your compiler.  Look for `-Wuninitialized` and `-finit-local-zero`.  One allows you to detect this problem, and the other one to prevent it (in a weird way - do not use the switch except for your learning).